# Raspbian Wheezy config.txt overclocking

Tags: pi-2, raspbian-wheezy, config.txt, overclocking

I looked on the Raspberry Pi documentation [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt.md) and I was trying to overclock my Raspberry Pi 2. But on the documentation page, I found options like `force-turbo` and other options that I didn't find in my `config.txt`, and I had made sure that I was looking in the right directory. Is my `config.txt` defective somehow? And, would it be fine if I just added the missing lines in. I am using Raspbian Wheezy (yes, it is up to date) on a Pi 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your RPi doesn't require all of the options listed in the documentation to be present in the `config.txt` file. Since most of them are optional, they're skipped to keep it cleaner and the processing time shorter.  You can safely add them in yourself.

**Option 2**:

You could also edit the overclock settings by running the command `sudo raspi-config` and selecting an overclock option.